# Configure NGINX to work with angular issue on reloading page

Tags: angular, nginx, server

Well I have read the deployment documentation to deploy an Angular 4 proyect with an NGINX server.But when I reload with a route for the angular app shows me this error:

http://www.mydomain.com.ec/swissecomer/myRoute

**code**: "MethodNotAllowedError"
**message**: "GET is not allowed"

Here is my conf file in my nginx server:

```
    upstream proyectoWeb {
        ip_hash;
        server localhost:8087;

    }

    server {

        listen 8088;
        proxy_pass proyectoWeb;
        server_name 200.31.25.34 192.168.5.27  www.mydomain.com localhost;
        root /u01/servidores/;


        location swissecomer/ {
            index index.html index.htm;
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
        }

        access_log /var/log/nginx/access_log combined;

    }
```

When i hit these urls, it shows the webpage just fine:

- http://www.mydomain.com.ec/swissecomer/index.html
- http://www.mydomain.com.ec/swissecomer/

But if i hit the next url http://www.mydomain.com.ec/swissecomer the ngix server keeps loading until it shows a timeout error in the browser.

Thanks for your responses.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try `location /swissecomer` instead the forward slash needs to match also for the location block to be used.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer, the block location needs a little change like this:

```
location swissecomer/ {
  index index.html index.htm;
  try_files $uri $uri/ /swissecomer/index.html;
}
```